# Matlab- Changing uniques date code values to more manageable data

Tags: matlab

I have a variable called sentDate which stores the month and day from Nov 27th - Dec 6th.Each day has a number of sentiment ratings that it represents therefore I need to assign unique day codes to each day so I can perform...

```
allSents(dayCodes==1)
```

So far I have managed to assign day codes using...

```
[a,b,dayCodes]=unique(sentDate);
[d,e,allSents]=unique(sentiment);
```

However the day codes take the last digit on the date e.g 27th becomes 7, 28th becomes 8, etc. I need it so the day codes start from 1 and increase for each day until the 6th of December, therefore 1-11.

Any idea on how I may do this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It may be useful to provide some sample data, input and desired output. In order to make your post easy to read, please do use the `{}` button to format code - there is a preview to look at.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the `datenum` function? then subtract off whatever offset to give the appropriate start day number.

Comment: No I haven't, could you elaborate on how this works? Sorry im new to Matlab

Comment: The reason I want it from 1:11 is because I am trying to do this---->

Comment: for i = 1 : 11, NSRPerDay(i) = (sum(allSents(dayCodes==i)==2) + sum(allSents(dayCodes==i)==1))/ sum(allSents(dayCodes==i)); end

Comment: its matlab's inbuilt function for converting a string with a textual date to an integer. datenum(date) - datenum(mystartday)

Comment: It didnt work because the dates are in the format Nov 27, Nov 28, etc. Is there a way to just assign a date code to each date by incrementing e.g 27 becomes 1, 28 becomes 2, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have a similar problem, by specifying stable in as a parameter e.g

```
[a,b,dayCodes]=unique(sentDate,'stable');
```

Will specify the daycodes in the same order as in sentDate.